# Как по нажатию на кнопку добавлять экземпляр моего класса в List без повторений

Tags: java, android

чтобы по нажатию добавлялся только один экземпляр в ArrayList например

Comment: может (если без повторений) лучше [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) использовать

Answer (score 3):

Если Вас интересует именно List/ArrayList, то у него есть метод [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

```
if (!myList.contains("new data")) myList.add("new data");
```

Comment: метод [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) встроенный ведь есть

Comment: @diraria а, точно. Я по привычке. У меня всегда кастомные списки и стандартный метод не подходит. Ответ удалю.

Comment: зачем удалять, просто напишите что есть стандартный метод)

Answer (score 2):

Вашему List нужно превратится в Set. Это коллекция без повторений.